# Executing part of code exactly 1 time inside Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, rightnow-crm

I have to query in my company's CRM Solution(Oracle's Right Now) for our 600k users, and update them there if they exist or create them in case they don't. To know if the user already exists in Right Now, I consume a third party WS. And with 600k users this can be a real pain due to the time it takes each time to get a response(around 1 second). So I managed to change my code to use `Parallel.ForEach`, querying each record in just 0,35 seconds, and adding it to a `List<User>` of records to be created or to be updated (Right Now is kinda dumb so I need to separate them in 2 lists and call 2 distinct WS methods).

My code used to run perfectly before multithread, but took too long. The problem is that I can't make a batch too large or I get a timeout when I try to update or create via Web Service. So I'm sending them around 500 records at once, and when it runs the critical code part, it executes many times.

```
Parallel.ForEach(boDS.USERS.AsEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1 }, row =>
{
    ...
    user = null;
    user = QueryUserById(row["USER_ID"].Trim());

    if (user == null)
    {
        isUpdate = false;
        gObject.ID = new ID();
    }
    else
    {
        isUpdate = true;
        gObject.ID = user.ID;
    }

    ... fill user attributes as generic fields ...

    gObject.GenericFields = listGenericFields.ToArray();

    if (isUpdate)
        listUserUpdate.Add(gObject);
    else
        listUserCreate.Add(gObject);

    if (i == batchSize - 1 || i == (boDS.USERS.Rows.Count - 1))
    {               
        UpdateProcessingOptions upo = new UpdateProcessingOptions();
        CreateProcessingOptions cpo = new CreateProcessingOptions();
        upo.SuppressExternalEvents = false;
        upo.SuppressRules = false;
        cpo.SuppressExternalEvents = false;
        cpo.SuppressRules = false;

        RNObject[] results = null;

        // <Critical_code>

        if (listUserCreate.Count > 0)
        {
            results = _service.Create(_clientInfoHeader, listUserCreate.ToArray(), cpo);
        }
        if (listUserUpdate.Count > 0)
        {
            _service.Update(_clientInfoHeader, listUserUpdate.ToArray(), upo);
        }
        // </Critical_code>

        listUserUpdate = new List<RNObject>();
        listUserCreate = new List<RNObject>();
    }
    i++;
});
```

I thought about using `lock` or `mutex`, but it isn't gonna help me, since they will just wait to execute afterwards. I need some solution to execute only ONCE in only ONE thread that part of code. Is it possible? Can anyone share some light?

Thanks and kind regards,
Leandro

Comment: use Monitor with double check. Like this `if(!initialized) lock(lockObj) if(!initialized){ doSomething(); initialized=true; }`

Comment: It would really help if you could include the variable declarations. Are `user`, `listUserUpdate` or `i` declared inside or outside the loop body?

Comment: @StevePuder all variables are declared outside loop

Comment: @Dmitry Dashko - you need to make that `initialized` bool be `volatile`.  See here: [Double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Microsoft_.NET_.28Visual_Basic.2C_C.23.29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Microsoft_.NET_.28Visual_Basic.2C_C.23.29) pattern.  This is usually used for singletons, but you're not making a singleton here so generic singletons like `Lazy<T>` do not apply.

It works like this:

1. Separate out your shared data into some sort of class:

   `class QuerySharedData {
       // All the write-once-read-many fields that need to be shared between threads 
       public QuerySharedData() {
           // Compute all the write-once-read-many fields.  Or use a static Create method if that's handy.
       }
   }`
2. In your outer class add the following:

   `object padlock; 
   volatile QuerySharedData data`
3. In your thread's callback delegate, do this:

   `if (data == null)
    {
       lock (padlock)
       {
           if (data == null)
           {
               data = new QuerySharedData(); // this does all the work to initialize the shared fields
           }
       }
    }
    var localData = data`

Then use the shared query data from `localData`  By grouping the shared query data into a subordinate class you avoid the necessity of making its individual fields volatile.

More about `volatile` here: [Part 4: Advanced Threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword).

**Update** my assumption here is that all the classes and fields held by `QuerySharedData` are read-only once initialized.  If this is not true, for instance if you initialize a list once but add to it in many threads, this pattern will not work for you.  You will have to consider using things like [Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the comments you're declaring the variables outside of the loop body. That's where your race conditions originate from.

Let's take variable `listUserUpdate` for example. It's accessed randomly by parallel executing threads. While one thread is still adding to it, e.g. in `listUserUpdate.Add(gObject);` another thread could already be resetting the lists in `listUserUpdate = new List<RNObject>();` or enumerating it in `listUserUpdate.ToArray()`.

You really need to refactor that code to

- make each loop run as independent from each other as you can by moving variables inside the loop body and
- access data in a synchronizing way using locks and/or concurrent collections